# How can I interpolate a string/fraction mixin variable in LESS?

Tags: less, less-mixins

I'm trying to my [grid system](https://github.com/corysimmons/lost) to LESS.

I'm using fractions as strings (there's a reason) and need to interpolate them in the `calc()` expression.

In Sass I can do this...

```
@mixin move($fraction: '1/1') {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(99.999999% * #{$fraction});
}
```

In LESS when I try this...

```
.move(@fraction: '1/1') {
  @_fraction: ~'@{fraction}';
  left: calc(99.999999% * @_fraction);
}
```

It ends up throwing a `Cannot read property 'numerator' of undefined` error.

Apparently LESS can tell it's a fraction but then it poops out.

Can any LESS pros enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape multiplication, addition, division, and subtraction in LESS or it will try output the calculated result. When less sees `*` in your code, it is trying to multiply `99.999999%` and `@_fraction`.

For example when LESS sees `calc(5px + 5px);` it will output `left: calc(10px);`. You can except it like this `~'calc(5px + 5px);'`.

Try using this code.

```
.move(@fraction: '1/1') {
  @_fraction: ~'@{fraction}';
  left: calc(~'99.999999% *' @_fraction);
}
```